# Trying to make factorial function

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make factorial calculation here.

When I run this code, it returns me number 5. I suppose this code loops only once, so only number 5(attr) is added to array. Am I right, and what should I do?

And I don't want solution, I want advice :)

```
def factorial attr
  array = []

  attr.downto(1) do |x|
    array << x
    array.reduce(:*)
  end
end

p factorial(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby returns the value of the last expression in the method as the value, and that's the `.downto` block.  Your code definitely loops, but it reduces "5" times, and discards the value!  So you're getting this, essentially:

```
(502)⚡️ irb
2.2.0 :001 > 25.downto(1) { |x| }
 => 25
```

Try moving your `reduce` statement outside of the block (below), so the `downto` stuffs the values into the array, *then* you reduce it using the `*` operation.

Comment: I should figure that out alone.. Thanks Nicky Kickiricky! :)

Comment: For fun after you get that working, try something like this on for size: `5.downto(1).reduce(:*)`.  Enumerable's are fun!